# Mongo db taking lot of virtual memory

Tags: mongodb

My mongo db collection size is appro 2Gb , and it is taking a lot of virtual memory when i continously hit database, my server ram is 48Gb , and mongo takes around 60Gb virtual memory.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your specific versions of MongoDB server and O/S. Do you only have a single database with the 2GB collection or are there other databases? How are you determining the 2GB collection size .. is that size on disk or the data size?

Comment: single database with 2Gb size on disk

Comment: mongo db version is 3.6.5 and os is windows server 2012

Comment: Have you changed any server settings from the default (particularly with regards to storage engine)? It would be helpful if you can edit your question to include the output of some commands in the `mongo` shell: `db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed`, `db.serverStatus().connections`, and  `db.stats()` (for your single database). If your problem is easily reproducible, it would also be worth upgrading to the latest 3.6.x release (currently 3.6.11) as there have been many improvements since 3.6.5.